# jQuery sortable tables get squeezed when row positions swapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have ui-sortable table implemented with jquery-ui. The rows can be dragged to swap positions. All works fine, but when the row is dragged, all the remaining rows in a table get squeezed to 1/5 size (columns overlapping).

here's the code that invokes the sortable script on the table:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var fixHelper = function (e, ui) {
      ui.children().each(function () {
          $(this).width($(this).width());
      });
      return ui;
  };

  $("tbody.sortable").sortable({
      helper: fixHelper,
      connectWith: "tbody.sortable",
      containment: "parent",
      dropOnEmpty: true,
      cancel: "tr.sort-disabled",
      receive: function (event, ui) {     
        ui.item.find("input[type='hidden']").val(this.id);
        sortableDummyRowsUpdate();  
      }
  });
});
```

When the dragged row is released to the new position, the table returns to normal. But while dragging everything looks awful

Comment: Your question title is way too generic. The title should be about the main question itself. Something like "Table getting squeezed while dragging row in jQuery sortable."

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon noticed that, and changed it.